# How to make Twitter app style Quick Actions on Android

Tags: android, user-controls, android-view, popupwindow

Is there any code that gives an example about how to implement the Quick Actions and Popdown menu that is displayed in the Twitter for Android app?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Funny you should ask that as I just have happened to finish working on this exact thing. You can check out the code here [simple quickactions for android](http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/)

Comment: Ok.  Two things.  1) Thank you so much for this code, you are the MAN!  2) You really posted a question and an answer to yourself? Really?

Comment: Yea, it was the only way I could think of to get it out there to people who would want it. :)

Comment: That's some good work though!  I have already brought it into a little test app I was working on!  Thanks!

Comment: EPIC! and hilarious question/answer!

Comment: +1, this helped me a LOT to build popup menus - I'm having problems enhancing it to add sub-menus though, getting all sort of nasty "android popupview token android.view.ViewRootXXXX is not valid; is your activity running?" exceptions when trying to show the sub-menu...