# Android: Can a view (not a viewgroup) contain another view?

Tags: android, view

I mean something like this

```
public class ConditionalEditText extends EditText implements TextWatcher
{
    TextView tv;
    ....
}
```

The TextView is supposed to be displayed only when the EditText satisfies some user specified condition.

I tried to do it like this

```
public class ConditionalEditText extends LinearLayout implements TextWatcher
{
    EditText edt;
    TextView tv;
    ....
}
```

but then I cannot specify different XML attributes for ***edt*** for different instances of the view in my main layout.

Answer (score 2):

no, only ViewGroup can have child Views

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a way to do this after all. You can anchor a PopupWindow containing any view(s) you want to another View, which is just what I wanted. I got the code to do so from this link and modified it for my needs.

http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/

[All thanks to Qberticus for making it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113106/how-to-make-twitter-app-style-quick-actions-on-android)