# The new twitter popup action

Tags: android, twitter, popupwindow

In my app there's a listview where I want a popup menu when an item is clicked, and I like the popup style that the new Twitter app have as below. I found some article around it (namely "quick action", e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113106/how-to-make-twitter-app-style-quick-actions-on-android)), but the style seems slightly different from twitter --- the menu is near the item, not just cover that item fully. I like the covering effect, is there any idea? Or could I do that by modification of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113106/how-to-make-twitter-app-style-quick-actions-on-android)?

PS: The item clicked is just COVERED by the popup menu(so it can't be seen at the moment), not the item ahead or follow the menu.

[How to make Twitter app style Quick Actions on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113106/how-to-make-twitter-app-style-quick-actions-on-android)

[image: TwitterImage]

Comment: its an `ExpandableListView`

Comment: @tyczj Can you explain it more specifically? I google some sample of ExpandableListView, but items seem to have drop down menu rather than a "covered" menu. PS: The item clicked is just COVERED by the popup menu, not the item ahead or follow the menu.